# jquery- Adding <option> tag inside <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down list like

```
<select name="select"> 
   <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
   <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

I want to add one extra `<option>` tag at the top like

```
<select name="select">
   <option value="value1" disabled selected>Value 1</option> 
   <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
   <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

How can i do it with jquery.

Comment: what have you attempted?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/prepend/. Also, you can't disable an `<option>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(
   '<option></option>',
   {value:"newvalue",text:"new option"}
).attr({
   disabled:"disabled",
   selected:"selected"
}).prependTo("select[name='select']")
```

Comment: can't i add disabled and selected attribute using this method?